# Retrieve only files from previous day

Tags: c#, file-io

I am currently developing a tool that will find all files, from the previous day, and move them from one folder to another on the same server. I am not hitting permission issues but I am getting stuck on the IF statement. Once the application finds a file, move to the other folder for further processing. My issue is that I am unable to find all files with just the date of yesterday and move them. I have supplied my code below and it is almost there (or at least that's what I tell myself). Thanks ahead of time for any assistance.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime past = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
        txtSourceFolderCount.Text = past.ToShortDateString();

        //efile originally start here
        var sourceDir = @"\\DIS2\EFilingXML\Archive";

        //application moves to archive
        var destDir = @"\\DIS2\EFilingXML";

        //only XML files are accepted
        //var pattern = "*.xml";

      DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDir);

      // Get info of each file into the directory
            foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
            {
                var creationTime = fi.LastWriteTime;

               if (creationTime == past && creationTime < DateTime.Today)
                {
                    fi.MoveTo(Path.Combine(destDir, fi.ToString()));
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: And your problem with this code is? (You forgot to specify what behavior you see...) Maybe you want to check if `dt` is inside some `DateTime` range (like `dt < today && dt >= today.AddDays(-1)`)?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thank you. good catch. I thought I did but I didn't. Is everything else looking correct as far as what I am wanting to do?

Comment: Might also check your event log to see if there's any permissions-related errors.

Comment: @Superstringcheese I have folder "God" rights and can do whatever is needed in this folder. I notice the dt is showing as 1/1/1600. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My issue is that I am unable to find all files with just the date of
>   yesterday and move them.

Two issues:

1) You are only using File.Name when you try to call the static System.IO.File.GetCreationTime method. This static method has no context other than the short File.Name with a value like "MyFile.xml" and no path attached.

2) You'll pickup files from today unless you add a second qualifier to your if statement like below:

```
        //gets all files in source directory & moves to destination directory(archive)
        foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(sourceDir).GetFiles(pattern))
        {
            DateTime dt = File.GetCreationTime(file.FullName);

            if (dt >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) && dt < DateTime.Today)
            {
                file.MoveTo(Path.Combine(destDir, file.Name));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nothing is being moved from the recommendations provided. I have cleaned up the code. Is something else missing?

Comment: Found it--your dt is not getting populated correctly because you're telling the static System.IO.File.GetCreationTime to find information on something just based on the short filename like "MyFile.xml" without any path information

Comment: so is that why you did an edit on the post for "file.FullName"? It hasn't jacked up yet in debug so that might be working! Thanks!

Comment: can you explain the AddDays(-1000) to me? A little confused because I thought it was -1 for the day to read yesterday.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was just testing on my own folder with items from the past 3 years! AddDays(-1) is good

Comment: (I responded as the site updated. Thank you!)so just change it back to -1 to find yesterday??

Comment: Yes you are correct with the DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) to start at midnight on the previous day